# Where is this shadow coming from?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-citadel

I am playing Citadel and am confounded by a shadow that shows up in the den where the private terminal/invite someone over/invite to party terminal is located. It is clearly a female shadow and my Shepard is male.

It looks like this :
[image]

And here you see me turn around. The shadow silhouette is still there Looks like this :
[image]

And here from a very different perspective.
[image]

Is there something I am missing here? Could this thing be for a future DLC?

Comment: sadly, there are no more DLCs coming out for me3.  The shadow looks like Liara's silhouette, is she in your party by any chance?  could be a glitch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no future DLCs coming out for Mass Effect 3 - all future Mass Effect content is going to be for the next Mass Effect games (which haven't officially been announced yet).

The shadow looks like either FemShep or Liara (more inclined to go with Liara due to the shape of the head) - since you're not playing FemShep and Liara isn't in the room this shadow is going to be a rendering issue or glitch of some kind.